# Notepad++ Restore Saved and Unsaved Tabs

Tags: notepad++, data-recovery

I've had Notepad++ for a number of years and I've created a lot of documents on it.

Some are saved as a file, but most are just `New X`, of which my latest was something like 84.

Anyway, as you can close down the program without these files disappearing, I've accumulated these 84 `unsaved` files over the past couple of years.

Today, I was using it all morning until I put the machine on standby for about 40 minutes. When I put it back on, I opened Notepad and found that all tabs are gone (including saved file tabs), and there is a `New 0`.

I know I've been playing a dodgy game with not saving these files for such a long time, and most contain utter #### (basic notes), but is there any possible way of restoring the tabs that were open just one hour ago?

Comment: Look `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\session.xml`. Maybe seach for previous (now deleted) its version.

Comment: Is AppData a hidden file? I don't see that

Comment: It is hidden folder. You may enable hidden files/folders visibility or simply enter the path `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++` in address field. PS. Do not execute NPP until recovering correct file and making its copy!

Comment: Ok, strange thing. Now I access `C` and there is no `USERS` listed?

Answer (score 6):

Please try checking `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup` directory. I have several files out there that are not appearing as tabs after opening Notepad++. It is very likely that all your notes are there.  The sooner the better for you to back them up and potentially look for some functionality to restore them.

If directory mentioned above doesn't exist, you may have custom backup settings. Open `Settings` > `Preferences...`, then in `Backup` tab you should find your custom path.

Note that in Notepad++ `File` menu you have a bunch of options to restore recent files. You can also save and restore sessions - that may be potential improvement for future.

For future, I recommend using Process Monitor from Sysinternals - it shows interaction of processes with file system and registry. It allowed me to find backup directory in few minutes.

---

Comment: Thanks, but I can't access the Notepad++ folder via File Explorer

Comment: Also, did a direct search for `sessions.xml` in `%USERPROFILE%` and came up "No Results Found"

Comment: Please check revised answer - you may find your backup through Notepad++ settings.

Comment: worked for me. thanks for saving all my files, i almost had a heart attack, you saved my life.